# How to graph a parabola using my quadratic equation program?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to graph solutions to quadratic problems using Python.

I'm new to coding and wrote a program to solve for quadratics. Now I want to graph it but can't figure out how.

```
import cmath

print('Solve the equation ax^2+bx+c=0')
a = float(input('a: '))
b = float(input('b: '))
c = float(input('c: '))
Discriminant = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
Solution1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(Discriminant))/(2*a)
Solution2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(Discriminant))/(2*a)
print('{0}^2+{1}x+{2}'.format(a, b, c))
print('The solution are {0} and {1}'.format(Solution1, Solution2))
h = (-b)/(2*a)
k = a*h**2+b*h+c
print('The origin is ({0},{1})'.format(h, k))
```

Need help writing code using `matplotlib` to graph an equation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation of matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would need something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# All the code you already written...

x = [i-50 for i in range(101)] # Array of x values
y = [a*(i**2)+b*i+c for i in x] # Array of corresponding y values
plt.plot(x, y)
```

This will plot each point (x[i], y[i]), i going from 0 to the length of the arrays.
Helpful youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuuvojEKHWo